# Error while trying to use edit.getBoolen on SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Based on solution I've gotten here I tried to make a **Switch button to make a Daily Notification.**

It didn't work well..
First I got the **"Cannot resolve method 'getBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)'"**
Than I tried to change the "editor" to the SharedPreferences and it was good but still:

The state of the switch button doesnt stay as it should be (When I turn the switch on and exiting the app it turns back to off) and basically even if the switch is shown off the notification still come out..
what do I do?
**I'm using fragments**

**EDIT: LukeJanyga Helped me along with quicklernear and ahmad!! But now the notification is not coming **

Here is the Settings.java:

```
public class Settings extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);


    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("הגדרות");

        final Switch dailySwitch = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.dailyTipSwitch);
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
        dailySwitch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("key", false));
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.commit();
        dailySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                boolean showNotifications = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("key",false);
                if (dailySwitch.isChecked() != showNotifications) {
                    editor.putBoolean("key",!showNotifications).commit();
                }
                else {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,20);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,50);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is the NotificationReceiver.java:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        repeatingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new
                NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("בוקר טוב אלוף! תאכל ותשתה טוב!"))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.NotificationText))
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.GoodMorningNotification))
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fragment is being recreated, so you need to set your `Switch` accordingly to what's stored in your preferences.

You use different keys every now and then - "key" vs "switchValue"

This line will always set it to false

```
editor.putBoolean("switchValue", dailySwitch.isChecked());
```

Read values from `SharedPreferences` not the `Editor`:

```
sharedPreferences.getBoolean("key",false);
```

And remember to retain the desired state when you recreate the view. Add:

```
dailySwitch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("switchValue", false));
```

Changes need to be committed in the editor:

```
editor.commit();
```

or

```
editor.apply();
```

EDIT: Ok, regarding what you mentioned in the comment - there is a really cool gist here:
https://gist.github.com/BrandonSmith/6679223

don't forget to add your receiver to `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thank you so much! It saving the switch state now! but the notification doesn't come out :\
edited it

Comment: @MatanCohen Updated the answer

Comment: Had a typo on the manifest ! Thank you so much! You're a life saver!!!!!!

Comment: Fixed the typo and it still doesn't send the notification :(
followed the Git. everything looks fine by what I did , any solution maybe?

Comment: What API level are you using?

Comment: How do I check it?

Comment: what version of Android are you testing it on?

Comment: Samsung galaxy s7 with android 7.0

Comment: Any solution? :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the editor object while committing the changes

// Save the changes in SharedPreferences

`editor.commit();` // commit changes

Use this.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
 boolean showNotifications = editor.getBoolean("key",false);
```

use the `sharedPreference` object to get the value:

```
 boolean showNotifications = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("key",false);
```

also use `editor.commit();` instead of `editor.apply();`